# Android, create file from input stream hangs inside while loop

Tags: java, android, retrofit, fileoutputstream

```
try {

    Log.d("TEST", "start converting...");

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "out.pdf");
    file.createNewFile();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = resp.getBody().in().read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        Log.d("TEST", "looping");
    }

    Log.d("TEST", "finish converting");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code should create a pdf file from an input stream. However it is stuck inside the while loop. It prints

```
looping
```

all the time. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: What's type is resp variable?

Comment: @DerGolem just a typo

Comment: @user230137 its of type Response, retrofit response object

Comment: Put a Log statement inside your while that prints out what read is.  Would be useful to know how many bytes it thought it read each time through.

Comment: @DerGolem not working because read is of type int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this javadoc for TypedInput:

> Read bytes as stream. Unless otherwise specified, this method may 
>       only be called once. It is the responsibility of the caller to close
>       the stream.

I would guess that calling in() creates a new InputStream every time.  As such, you'll never get out of the while loop because you'll have a fresh InputStream each time through.

Instead, just call in() once like so and see if that fixes things:

```
    InputStream in = null;

    try {

        Log.d("TEST", "start converting...");

        File file = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "out.pdf");
        file.createNewFile();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

         in = resp.getBody().in();

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            Log.d("TEST", "looping");
        }

        Log.d("TEST", "finish converting");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
             in.close();
        }
    }
```